# Remover linha da tabela após excluir via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, front-end

Tenho uma tabela que mostra registros de alunos, e cada linha tem um botão para excluir o aluno, e a exclusão é feita via AJAX. Gostaria de dar um fadeOut na linha que for excluída, então no success do AJAX fiz o seguinte:

```
success:function(){
                swal("Excluído!", "O aluno foi removido com sucesso.", "success");
                btnExcluir.closest('tr').fadeOut();
            }
```

O problema é que todas as linhas estão sendo removidas. Tentei também com parent().parent() mas mesmo assim ocorre o mesmo.

Segue o trecho da minha tabela:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{$aluno['NM_NIS_ALU']}}</td>
    <td>{{$aluno['ST_NOME_ALU']}}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{$aluno['IDADE']}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs acao" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAluno{{$aluno['ID_ALUNO_ALU']}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs acao delete-aluno" data-token="{{csrf_token()}}" data-id="{{$aluno['ID_ALUNO_ALU']}}"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Excluir</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, por que isso está ocorrendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegue o elemento `tr` antes de fazer a requisição ajax e depois de um fadeOut.

Você ta pegando todos elementos que possuem a classe `delete-aluno` e pegando suas respectivas `trs`, dessa forma irá retornar 3 `trs` (no exemplo abaixo) e não apenas uma.

Você tem que pegar o elemento `tr` referente ao `delete-aluno` que você está fazendo a ação do onclick.

Segue um exemplo funcional.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".delete-aluno").click(function() {
                var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'retornoAjax.php',
                    data: {

                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(retorno){
                        if (retorno.success) {
                            $tr.fadeOut();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Diego</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs acao"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs acao delete-aluno"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Excluir</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Diego 2</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs acao"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs acao delete-aluno"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Excluir</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Diego 3</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs acao"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs acao delete-aluno"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Excluir</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

retornoAjax.php

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array("success" => "true"));
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado, amigo!